# In rdkit, how to preserve stereochemistry in a SMARTS subgraph?

Tags: computational-chemistry, cheminformatics

In rdkit, when doing a MCS search for molecules bearing a chirality center, (how) is it possible to preserve the stereochemical information when exporting the subgraph to a SMARTS string?

Consider the following three molecules:

```
>>> mol_ccw = Chem.MolFromSmiles('C1=C[C@H](Cl)CCC1')
>>> mol_cw  = Chem.MolFromSmiles('C1=C[C@@H](Cl)CCC1')
>>> mol_lin = Chem.MolFromSmiles('C=C[C@H](Cl)CCC')
```

Doing a chirality-sensitive subgraph search leads to the somewhat expected result:

```
>>> rdFMCS.FindMCS([mol_ccw, mol_cw], matchChiralTag=True).smartsString
'[#6](=[#6])-[#6]-[#6]-[#6]-[#6]-[#17]'
>>> rdFMCS.FindMCS([mol_ccw, mol_lin], matchChiralTag=True).smartsString
'[#6]=[#6]-[#6](-[#17])-[#6]-[#6]-[#6]'
>>> rdFMCS.FindMCS([mol_cw, mol_lin], matchChiralTag=True).smartsString
'[#6]-[#6]-[#6]-[#6]-[#6]'
```

The subgraph over `mol_cw` and `mol_lin` includes the stereocenter. But unfortunately, the chirality information is not stored in the SMARTS string, and using `[#6]=[#6]-[#6](-[#17])-[#6]-[#6]-[#6]` for a chirality-sensitive substructure match leads to the expected result of the pattern made from that SMARTS string matching all three molecules:

```
>>> patt = Chem.MolFromSmarts('[#6]=[#6]-[#6](-[#17])-[#6]-[#6]-[#6]')
>>> len({mol_cw, mol_ccw, mol_lin}.GetSubstructMatches(patt, useChirality=True))
1
```

Manually inserting a lazy `@H` or a `&*&H1` at the stereocenter leads -of course- to the desired result:

```
>>> patt = Chem.MolFromSmarts('[#6]=[#6]-[#6@H](-[#17])-[#6]-[#6]-[#6]')
>>> len({mol_ccw, mol_lin}.GetSubstructMatches(patt, useChirality=True))
1
>>> len(mol_cw.GetSubstructMatches(patt, useChirality=True))
0
```

Now, when matching `mol_ccw` and `mol_lin`, how do I get the stereochemistry-aware SMARTS string `[#6]=[#6]-[#6&*&H1](-[#17])-[#6]-[#6]-[#6]` as the substructure in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested in this topic: I just learned that this is a bug that *should* already be filed on GitHub, but apparently the developers themselves do not find it anymore - probably that's why I didn't find it. Nonetheless, the bug is known and will be fixed in the next release.